# DI of external modules not working

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am having problems with dependency injection of an external module:

```
export class DealsModel {

    foo() {
        console.log('foo');
    };
}
```

Specifically this code:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';
import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { DealsModel } from './models/dealsModel';

@Component({
    selector: 'search-form',
    viewInjector: [DealsModel],
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '/Deals/SearchForm'
})
class SearchFormComponent {

    constructor(da:DealsModel) {
        console.log(da);
    }
}
```

fails because the .js generated (partially submitted here) is:

```
SearchFormComponent = __decorate([
    angular2_1.Component({
        selector: 'search-form',
        viewInjector: [deals_Model_1.DealsModel],
    }),
    angular2_1.View({
        templateUrl: '/Deals/SearchForm'
    }), 
    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [DealsModel]) // <-- problem
], SearchFormComponent);
return SearchFormComponent;
```

Basically the `__metadata` receives the wrong reference (should get `deals_Model_1.DealsModel`) now this is solvable with this approach:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';
import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
import * as dm from './models/dealsModel';

@Component({
    selector: 'search-form',
    viewInjector: [dm.DealsModel],
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '/Deals/SearchForm'
})
class SearchFormComponent {

    constructor(da:dm.DealsModel) {
        console.log(da);
    }
}

bootstrap(SearchFormComponent);
```

But it's obviously an hack.
Now the question is, should I submit an issue or am I missing something obvious?

I am using `alpha.31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the question is, should I submit an issue or am I missing something obvious

Already reported and fixed : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3663

You can use `ntypescript` at the moment to get this fix : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript